# WindowsUpdate of .Net 3.5 SP1 (KB951847) failed to install several times. .Net 3.5 SP1 already installed

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I have a Windows 2003 server x86, which I have manually installed .Net 3.5 SP1, but now, the Windows Update:

> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service
>   Pack 1 and .NET Framework 3.5 Family
>   Update for .NET versions 2.0 through
>   3.5 (KB951847) x86

failed to install with error:

> Error Code: 0x80070643
>   Try to
>   install the update again, or request
>   help from one of the following
>   resources.

**What to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the installation package outside of Windows Update? You find the package in `%WINDIR%\SoftwareDistribution\Download\Install` once you've tried to install it. Normally, this way you get better error messages

**Updated**: You may try this:
Stop service Windows Updates from services.msc and delete or rename SoftwareDistribution folder afterwards. Start Windows Updates again and it should recreate the folder structure (at least when new updates arrive)

Comment: There is an old package in there (KB958481). I'm running in right now, but it get stuck. Maybe this is the real problem...

Comment: Maybe it's just an old installation package...Try again or see my updated answer to "clean" this downloaded stuff

Comment: Embarrassing: There problem was not enough disk space on the system disk.

Comment: I had this one before with SP3 for SQL Server ;)